# No Ads But Still Getting Advertising Identifier Error on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, itunes, iad, idfa

I am trying to submit my game for review on iTunes Connect but it keeps telling me that my game is using Advertising Identifier (IDFA) al though my game has no ads at all. I can't keep it on 'No' since it keeps giving me that error.

When I select Yes, it gives me 3 options to choose from and I have no idea what they are since there are literally no ads in my game. The options are:

1. Serve advertisements in the app
2. Attribute app installation to a previously served advertisement
3. Attribute an action taken within this app to a previously served advertisement

How do I fix this? I have no ads so why is it asking me to select these options?

Comment: What frameworks have you included in your app?

Comment: No frameworks at all. I am using FMOD as my audio engine and using a 3rd party plugin for Unity to integrate GameCenter and iCloud. That's it!

Comment: Perhaps try the grep command suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31451278/xamarin-ios-dll-use-of-advertising-identifier-idfa?rq=1

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand how can I use that command in Unity?

Comment: You use it in terminal to scan through your project and try and identify which component contains the advertising identifier. This is effectively what Apple does. If you can't find it then you may have to raise a support incident with Apple and ask them why the submission process is detecting the advertising identifier

Comment: Okay, I did a grep search and found out that 3rd party plugin and my analytics are using the Advertising Identifier. Should I select Yes then? If yes, then what option should I go with?

Comment: You need to find out from the authors why they are using it, but it sounds like they probably shouldn't be using it.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. I will try to ask them.